# How to insert data using a checkbox inside a while loop php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add the value of a checkbox to the specific row in the database. It adds the value to the wrong rows each time. I tried adding a hidden input with a different value.

```
 if (isset($_POST['save_task'])) {
                $count=count($_POST["pro_id"]);
                
                    $query = "INSERT INTO client_program_task_activities (task_id, activity_type, type_id, show_status)
                      VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
                    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $query);
                   
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssss', $_POST['task_id'][$i], $_POST['type'][$i], $_POST['pro_id'][$i],  $_POST['show_status'][$i]);
                    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                }
                 }

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tasks  WHERE user_id='$user_id' ORDER BY date_added DESC ";
                                $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
                                $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                                if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                                   
                                    echo ' <form action="task_day.php" method="post" > 
                                  <table >
                                    <tr>
                                      <th> ADD TASK</th>
                                      <th> TASK NAME</th>
                                      <th>KCAL</th>
                                    </tr>';
                                    
                                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                         echo '<input type="hidden" name="task_id[]" value="'; echo $task_id; echo '">';
                                        echo '<input type="hidden" name="pro_id[]" value="'.$row['pro_id']. '">';
                                        echo '<input type="hidden" name="type[]" value="test">';
                                        echo '<input name=show_status[] type="hidden" value="0">
                                                  <td><input name=show_status[] type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
                                                  <td>'.$row['task_name'].'</td>
                                                  </tr>';
                                    }
                                    echo ' </table>
                               <button name="save_task" type="submit" >Save task</button>
                   </form>';
                                    
                                }
                
                
                                ?>
```

Comment: prepare the statement once before the loop and assign new values in the loop before executing the query/statement

Comment: FYI - your generated HTML is invalid. You cannot insert `input` elements as direct children of a `table` - they must be in a table cell

Comment: Also - there is no opening `TR` tag inside the `while` loop but there is a closing `</TR>` tag...

Comment: You go some way to using `prepared statements` as you should when dealing with potentially damaging user supplied data but then ignore that and embed a variable (`$user_id`) directly in the `select` query and thus open your code to sql injection possibilities

Comment: Thank you, I fixed the html and the TR tag. so should I just move the for loop to after I prepared the statement?

Comment: You prepare the statement once ( before the loop ) and bind the placeholders to variables at this stage too. Once inside the loop - assign values to the variables and execute

Comment: I edited the question. Is that what you mean?

Comment: nearly yes. The `bind_param` should also be done just once - outside the loop.

Comment: I edited it again, It this what you meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps this might help you understand what I was implying by creating and binding the prepared statements outside the loop.

```
<?php
    # test that ALL fields are present before trying to
    # assign them to variables or process them further.
    if( isset( 
        $_POST['save_task'],
        $_POST['task_id'],
        $_POST['type'],
        $_POST['pro_id'],
        $_POST['show_status']
    )) {
    
        # prepare the statement ONCE - and bind placeholders to variables.
        # in `mysqli` these variables do not need to exist at this point
        # whereas in PDO they do.
        
        $sql='insert into `client_program_task_activities` ( `task_id`, `activity_type`, `type_id`, `show_status`) values ( ?, ?, ?, ? )';
        $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bind_param( 'ssss', $tid, $type, $pid, $status );
        
        foreach( $_POST['pro_id'] as $i => $pid ){
            $tid=$_POST['task_id'][$i];
            $type=$_POST['type'][$i];
            $status=$_POST['show_status'][$i];
            
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
    
    
    # query to find data for table display
    $sql = 'select `task_id`, `task_name`, `pro_id` from `tasks` where `user_id`=? order by `date_added` desc';
    $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
    $stmt->bind_param( 's', $user_id );
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result( $tid, $task, $pid );
    
    
    # prepare output for table rows
    $rows=[];
    while( $stmt->fetch() ){
        $rows[]=sprintf(
            '<tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="task_id[]" value="%s" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="pro_id[]" value="%s" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="type[]" value="test" />
                    
                    <input name="show_status[]" type="hidden" value="0" />
                    <input name="show_status[]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
                </td>
                <td>%s</td>
                <td>### ENERGY ###</td>
            </tr>',
            
            $tid,
            $pid,
            $task
        );
    }
    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt->close();
    
    
    
    
    
    # print the formatted table
    printf('
        <form action="task_day.php" method="post"> 
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>ADD TASK</th>
                    <th>TASK NAME</th>
                    <th>KCAL</th>
                </tr>
                %s
            </table>
            <button name="save_task" type="submit" >Save task</button>
        </form>',
        implode( PHP_EOL, $rows )
    );
    
?>
```

Without knowing the table schema I could not be sure if the following is correct but based upon the table design shown this appears to work OK.

```
<?php

    require 'db.php';

    $user_id=!empty( $_GET['user_id'] ) ? $_GET['user_id'] : false;
    
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    
        <?php
            /*
            based upon following rudimentary table schema
            
            mysql> describe tasks;
            +------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
            | Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
            +------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
            | id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
            | task_id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0                 |                |
            | task_name  | varchar(50)      | NO   |     | 0                 |                |
            | pro_id     | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0                 |                |
            | user_id    | varchar(50)      | NO   | MUL | 0                 |                |
            | date_added | timestamp        | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
            +------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+


            mysql> describe client_program_task_activities;
            +---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
            | Field         | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
            +---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
            | id            | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
            | task_id       | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
            | activity_type | varchar(50)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
            | type_id       | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | 0       |                |
            | show_status   | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
            +---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
            
            */
            
            
            # test that ALL fields are present before trying to
            # assign them to variables or process them further.
            if( isset(
                $user_id,
                $_POST['save_task'],
                $_POST['task_id'],
                $_POST['type'],
                $_POST['pro_id'],
                $_POST['show_status']
            ) && !empty( $user_id ) ) {
            
                # prepare the statement ONCE - and bind placeholders to variables.
                # in `mysqli` these variables do not need to exist at this point
                # whereas in PDO they do.
                try{
                    
                    $sql='insert into `client_program_task_activities` ( `task_id`, `activity_type`, `type_id`, `show_status`) values ( ?, ?, ?, ? )';
                    $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
                    $stmt->bind_param( 'ssss', $tid, $type, $pid, $status );
                    
                    foreach( $_POST['task_id'] as $key => $tid ){
                        $status = in_array( $tid, array_keys( $_POST['show_status'] ) ) ? 1 : 0;
                        $pid=$_POST['pro_id'][ $key ];
                        $type=$_POST['type'][ $key ];
                        $stmt->execute();
                    }
                    
                    $stmt->close();
                    
                }catch( mysqli_sql_exception $e ){
                    echo $e->getMessage(); # Do NOT display errors in final, production code!!!
                    #printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r( $_POST, true ) );
                }
            }
            
            
            
            
            
            
            # query to find data for table display
            try{
                
                $sql = 'select `task_id`, `task_name`, `pro_id` from `tasks` where `user_id`=? order by `date_added` desc';
                $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
                $stmt->bind_param( 's', $user_id );
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->bind_result( $tid, $task, $pid );
                
            }catch( mysqli_sql_exception $e ){
                echo $e->getMessage(); # Do NOT display errors in final, production code!!!
            }
            
            
            # prepare output for table rows
            /*
                Removed hidden field `show_status` and assigned
                the task ID as the index to `show_status`
            */
            $rows=[];
            while( $stmt->fetch() ){
                $rows[]=sprintf(
                    '<tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="hidden" name="task_id[]" value="%1$d" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="pro_id[]" value="%2$d" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="type[]" value="%3$s" /><!-- using task name as value rather than "test" -->
                            <input name="show_status[%1$d]" type="checkbox" value="1" /><!-- using task ID as index -->
                        </td>
                        <td>%3$s</td>
                        <td>### ENERGY ###</td><!-- unclear what this content will be ~ assumed energy due to column name KCAL -->
                    </tr>',
                    
                    $tid,
                    $pid,
                    $task
                    
                );
            }
            $stmt->free_result();
            $stmt->close();
            
            
            
            
            
            # print the formatted table
            # action="task_day.php" 
            printf('
                <form method="post"> 
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ADD TASK</th>
                            <th>TASK NAME</th>
                            <th>KCAL</th>
                        </tr>
                        %s
                    </table>
                    
                    <button name="save_task" type="submit">Save task</button>
                </form>',
                implode( PHP_EOL, $rows )
            );
            
        ?>
    
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It updates the table, but it still updates the wrong rows.

Comment: how can it update the wrong rows... there are no `update` statements only `insert` and `select`??

Comment: Sorry I meant insert. So the 0 value sometimes insert in the wrong row. It's like sometimes it takes the value of the hidden input and ignores the checkbox

Comment: if the checkbox is `unchecked` then the value submitted will be zero - as per your form design. If that is not the intention - change the value to `banana` etc and test, in PHP, whether there is a value submitted for `show_status` and if it is `banana` do something else. Or are you saying that even when `checked` the value `0` sometimes gets inserted? I can't see how that would be

Comment: Yeah even if it's checked, then sometimes the value 0 gets inserted, and even if it's not checked, the value 1 gets inserted

Comment: OK - if you look at the `$_POST` values that are submitted you will notice a discrepency between the number of fields submitted for `task_id`,`pro_id`,`type` and `show_status` due to there being two `show_status` fields in the form

Comment: can you add the table schemas to the question?